# Use count of a Field in One Table to Update a Field in Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in an Access DB: `[Importing GTRX]` and `[Cells_2G]`. I want to update `[cells_2G].TRX900` with the count of related `[importing GTRX]` records. To do this I wrote two SQL but they failed to update.

First code:

```
UPDATE
  [Importing GTRX] INNER JOIN Cells_2G 
  ON [Importing GTRX].[Cell Name] = Cells_2G.[Cell Name]
SET
  cells_2g.trx900=Count([importing gtrx].frequency)
WHERE 
 (
  (
   [Importing GTRX].frequency>=1 
   And 
   [Importing GTRX].frequency<=124
  ) 
 ) 
 AND 
 [Importing GTRX].[active status]="activated"
;
```

When I run this query it said:

> Your query does not include the specified expression TRX900 as part of aggregation function

When I add: `group by [cells_2g.trx900]`, I face another error.

second code:

```
UPDATE
  Cells_2G inner join
  (
   SELECT [Cell Name], count(*) AS TRX900
   FROM [importing GTRX]
   WHERE 
    [Active status]="activated" 
    AND [Importing GTRX].frequency>=1 
    And  [Importing GTRX].frequency<=124
   GROUP BY [cell name]
  ) AS TT ON TT.[Cell Name] = Cells_2G.[Cell Name]
SET
  cells_2g.trx900=TT.TRX900
;
```

When I try to run this one, Access says:

> Operation must use an updateable query.

Now how can I do this?

Your helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of joining, you could try and use an online subquery to compute the target value, like:

```
UPDATE [Cells_2G]
SET [TRX900] = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM [Importing GTRX]
    WHERE (
        [Importing GTRX].[Cell Name] = [Cells_2G].[Cell Name]
        AND [Importing GTRX].frequency >= 1 
        AND [Importing GTRX].frequency <= 124
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks GMB.  But again it says "Operation must use an updateable query".  I am using MS Access 2013.

Comment: I just find a way. Run a make table query to produce counts in a new table and then run a simple update query. But it looks like a little stupid solution!